# Render Errors In ExpandableTextView

Tags: android

I don't know why I got **Render Errors** when adding `ExpandableTextView`

```
 <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/expand_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_linear"
        expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="4"
        expandableTextView:animDuration="200">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


    </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
```

The dependency is `compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'`

Below is the complete XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/question_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_linear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/up_vote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/vote"
                android:src="@drawable/vote_up" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vote_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="12"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/accepted_answer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/accepted"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/correct" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
            xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/expand_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_linear"
            expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="4"
            expandableTextView:animDuration="200">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


        </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: can you write full error log?

Comment: This error occurred just when i add the ExpandableTextView tag to XML file, nothing more than that

Comment: Added answer.. try this it should work..

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help

Comment: check another update... use this exact Ids mentioned here.. It will word.. I checked with my android studio project and it works fine..

Comment: Yes it's working, thank you very much @AalapPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are missing namespace error. Try using this one
You can go [here](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView/issues/10) for its explaination.

```
<com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/expand_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="4"
    expandableTextView:animDuration="200">
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/expandable_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#666666" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
```

Comment: The code i just wrote above is inside RelativeLayout inside a CardView, is that related to the problem ??

Comment: Do you have xmlns of expandabletextview in your xml files root ?

Comment: It worked out when i added the ImageButton, i didn't think that ImageButton is forcible because i thought to add a "show more" TextView instead of it, but thank you for your help

Comment: yes as per their implementation they require image button there.. I am glad to help, thank you.

Comment: I got another render error which is "failed to instantiate one or more classes", do you know what is the reason ?

Comment: what did you change ?

Comment: Just the orientation to "horizontal" as vertical in not useful for my layout

Comment: I think it wont help as they need both textview and imagebutton aligned vertically... when you use 3rd patry library you have to adapt their pattern, if its too much trouble handling then try observing other libraries which achieves your requirements..